# Optimal Intraclass correlation coefficient computation method

Tags: reliability, intraclass-correlation, psychology

I am hoping to compute intraclass correlations to evaluate interrater reliability (IRR) for interviews conduct with participants in a clinical psychology study. Specifically, we want to determine IRR for sums of symptom scores made in interviews with participants (e.g., for determining agreement for rating a total score for depression symptoms).

We will have a relatively large sample of 200 participants, so in this case, **which specific research team member interviewed and made initial ratings of participants varied**. A second rater will listen to recordings of the interview and will make their own ratings, but **who this second interviewer is will vary** rather than having the same person listen to all or a subset of recordings.

So, to summarize, we will have two columns of data: One with ratings from the original interviewer (with participants being interviewed by different interviewers) and a second based on ratings from a second researcher (though the specific researcher will vary within the column; not the same person). The specific interviewer varies within each of the two columns then.

I believe that we want to focus on absolute agreement (rather than consistency) and to report mean/average measures agreement rather than single measures agreement. I am unclear though whether a one-way random or two-way random model is more appropriate (a two-way mixed model doesn't seem to fit based on what I've read). Based on reading Khoo & Li (2016), I believe a two-way random model is more appropriate given that our goal is to determine reliability across clinical raters with training in structured interviewing and clinical topics, but I would like input on this point in particular (whether a one-way random or two-way random approach is more suitable).

Comment: I would trust what you found by Khoo and li. If I remember right they have a very comprehensive guide to model choice. The ICC has some major draw-backs, if you sample have too little variation, you can get wrongly small results. Therefor ALWAYS present you results with a bland-altman plot, showing the whole dataset and possibly systematic problems.